# Autopopulate Lookup Field with Account ID using an Apex Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, salesforce-id, record-type

We have a custom object called `Internal_Submission__c` with a lookup field called `Company__c`, I need to have this lookup field autopopulate via an an Apex trigger which would take the `AccountID` from the `Employer_Account__c` field on a parent object `Job_Order__c`.

`Job_Order__c` is a parent of `Internal_Submission__c`, and I essentially need the Id from `Employer_Account__c` on `Job_Order__c` to populate on the `Company__c` field on the `Internal_Submission__c` object when the record type has been changed from Submission to Placement. I have not gotten to the record type update yet, if it would work for either record type right now that would be okay.

The code below is throwing a method error on the [SETId].get(Id) on the last line, I think it is something with the methods I am using and working with Ids, but they all seem to be okay.

```
trigger SetAccountID on Internal_Submission__c (before insert, before update) {
    Map<Id,Id>Accounts = new Map<Id,Id>();

    List<Job_Order__c> listGL = new List<Job_Order__c>();
    Set<Id> AccountId = new Set<Id>();
    for (Internal_Submission__c a: Trigger.new)
    {
        AccountId.add(a.Job_Order__r.Employer_Account__r.Id);
    }
    system.debug(AccountId +'@@'+AccountId.size());
    listGL = [Select ID, Employer_Account__r.Id from Job_Order__c where Id in :AccountId];
    system.debug('@@@'+listGL);
    for (Job_Order__c objJobOrder: listGL)
    {
        if(!Accounts.containsKey(objJobOrder.ID) && objJobOrder.Employer_Account__c != null)
            Accounts.put(objJobOrder.ID,objJobOrder.Employer_Account__c);
    }
    for (Internal_Submission__c a: Trigger.new)
    {
        if(AccountID.containsKey(a.Job_Order__c) && a.Company__c == null){
            a.Company__c = AccountId.get(a.Job_Order__r.Employer_Account__r.Id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any update on this?

Comment: Hi @EricSSH, I made some edits and posted them below Bachovski's answer, and I am getting a new error now, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In situations like this, I prefer to use a bit of a hack that drastically simplifies the apex code. The trick is to use a formula field (if you don't mind having an extra field that only helps simplify this situation). Formula fields are evaluated on-the-fly, including during triggers - even though you can't directly access relationships in a trigger, a formula field can.

Make a new formula field on the Internal_Submission__c object that has this as the formula: Job_Order__r.Employer_Account__c - this will evaluate to be the ID of the account. Then update your trigger's code to something like this:

```
trigger SetAccountID on Internal_Submission__c (before insert, before update) {

for (Internal_Submission__c a: Trigger.new)
{
    if(a.Company__c == null){
        a.Company__c = a.YOUR_FORMULA_FIELD__c;        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You can't use `trigger.new` and reference parent object's fields. `trigger.new` only contains fields on the actual targeted record in the trigger. What you should do in your first for loop instead of:
`for (Internal_Submission__c a: Trigger.new)`
try
`for (Internal_Submission__c a: [SELECT Job_Order__r.Employer_Account__r.Id FROM Internal_Submission__c WHERE Id IN :trigger.newMap.keySet()])`

2) In your `listGL` why don't you query `Employer_Account__c` rather than `Employer_Account__r.Id`?

3) Again, same thing in your last loop, you're referencing `Job_Order__r.Employer_Account__r.Id` but you haven't queried that (replace `trigger.new` with the same query as I specified in 1))

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Bachovski, I made the following edits to the trigger, but it is still throwing an error on the Accounts.put method.  It says the key type SOBJECT:Job_Order__c for Map  is incompatible.  Can you not use an ID as a key in a map or am I calling the wrong thing in the code?  Thanks again for your help:

```
trigger SetAccountID on Internal_Submission__c (before insert, before update) {
Map<Id,Id>Accounts = new Map<Id,Id>();

List<Job_Order__c> listGL = new List<Job_Order__c>();
Set<Id>AccountId = new Set<Id>();
for (Internal_Submission__c a: [SELECT Job_Order__r.Employer_Account__r.ID 
                                FROM Internal_Submission__c
                                WHERE Id IN :trigger.newMap.keySet()])
{
    AccountId.add(a.Job_Order__r.Employer_Account__r.Id);
}
system.debug(AccountId +'@@'+AccountId.size());
listGL = [Select ID, Employer_Account__c from Job_Order__c where Id in :AccountId];
system.debug('@@@'+listGL);
for (Job_Order__c objJobOrder: listGL)
{
    if(!AccountId.containsKey(/*(objJobOrder)*/ (objJobOrder.Employer_Account__c /*!= null*/)))
        Accounts.put(objJobOrder,objJobOrder.Employer_Account__c);
}
for (Internal_Submission__c a: [SELECT Job_Order__r.Employer_Account__r.ID 
                                FROM Internal_Submission__c
                                WHERE Id IN :trigger.newMap.keyset()])
{
    if(AccountID.containsKey(a.Job_Order__c) && a.Company__c == null){
        a.Company__c = AccountId.get(a.Job_Order__r.Employer_Account__r.Id);
    }
}
}
```